# Как привести полученный объект к его наследнику, если объект точно можно привести, но он был получен с помощью jsonConvert из строки?

Tags: c#, парсер, клиент-сервер, newtonsoft.json

Всем привет!
Есть такая ситуация:
С сервера приходит ответ и с помощью newtonsoft.jsonConvert преобразуется в базовый класс `DataBasic`. У этого класса есть наследники: `SomeData1`, `SomeData2`, `SomeData3`.

Проблема:
Не получается явно привести результат прошедший обработку конвертером (то есть ответ сервера в виде DataBasic) к его наследникам. `(SomeData1)serverResponse; //error`

Вопрос:
Можно ли как-нибудь привести ответ к классам наследникам? Или придётся писать парсер?

P.S. То есть ест ли фича, чтобы сразу из json строки шло преобразование к максимально далёкому наследнику, а только потом downcast`ить его к базовому?

Comment: Так вы ответ какого типа ожидаете на запрос, в тот тип и преобразуйте изначально.

Comment: `serverResponse.GetType()` что выдаёт?

Comment: Экземпляр абстрактного класса невозможно создать. / Показывайте код.

Comment: Как раз этот DataBasic был создан, чтобы объединить общие данные для классов наследников.

Comment: Насчёт абстрактного, я ошибся, там базовый класс.